# iOS Safari browser captures only initial frames from a video on canvas and duplicates all captured images

Tags: video, mobile-safari, getusermedia, drawimage

- We are using Twilio Video JavaScript SDK and making video calls in web browser (iphone ios=safari,android=chrome).
- During video call user can capture images.
- Capture Image actually uses javascript drawImage function to draw an image from canvas which has live video call media.
- Video plays properly in Safari, but in capture image functionality it doesnt behave as expected every time.
- sometimes not always, safari duplicates such frames in all the captured images. For example if video was ON for 10 minutes and user capture images 10 times then from the 5th second to 8th minute , all the 10 images
  will be of 5th second's scene.
- this duplicate images issue doesn't appear everyime. sometimes when issue occurs and if we guide user to reset their browser setting, then next time it works fine and all the images comes of
  different scenes as expected.
- Issue appeared in iOS 11.2, 12.3 and 13.1

javascript code :

```
        var width;
        var height;
        var video;

        video = document.querySelectorAll('#outremote_video video')[0];

        if (video != undefined && video != null && video != "" && video.videoWidth != 0 && video.videoHeight != 0) {
            width = video.videoWidth;
            height = video.videoHeight;

        }

        var img = new Image();
        var canvas = document.getElementById('screenshotcanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (width && height) {

            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            console.error('height ' +canvas.height+ 'width  '+canvas.width);

            //take video view on canvas
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);    
            var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            imageDataList.push(imageData);
        }
```

then I upload Blob imageData to the server. What is wrong with safari? why it behaves unexpected sometime without any error message. Can there be any cache issue ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how you invoke the code shown in your example. Also, you mention uploading Blobs, but your code uses `toDataURL()` rather than `toBlob()`. Please explain your data handling a bit. The code you have looks correct.  (And, Safari's WebRTC implementation is, at present, amateurish. )